# Using @@PROCID to return name of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

We are migrating from Sybase to MSSQL 2016, and have triggers on some Sybase tables which we have ported from SYB to MSSQL. These triggers are really useful in SYB because they tell us the proc wrote the change to those tables so we know where to look when we have any issues.

Unfortunately, (object_name(@@procid)) does not work the same in MSSQL as it does in SYB (In MSSQL it is giving us the trigger name which is not very useful…), so we need to find a solution to this issue. Any help?

Comment: Does this help you? [Using @@PROCID to return correct name of SQL Server procedures, functions and triggers](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3278/using-procid-to-return-correct-name-of-sql-server-procedures-functions-and-triggers/).

Comment: Thanks, I see this "write to the my_data_log table instead of using a trigger" - this would be a pain as we need to rewrite more than 50 triggers from Sybase. Any other alternative?

Comment: I would say setting up a SQL Audit is in order, then. See [Lightweight SQL Server Procedure Auditing without using SQL Server Auditing - MS Blogs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jenss/2009/06/08/light-weight-sql-server-procedure-auditing-without-using-sql-server-auditing/). Depending on what you need to track